# Xcode 11 crashes when moving a view controller from one storyboard to another. Is there another way to do this?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have a storyboard with about 15 scenes on it. I want to move a couple of scenes to a new storyboard.

1. I created the new storyboard
2. I selected the view controller on the main storyboard
3. Cmd + x
4. I navigated to the new storyboard
5. Cmd + v
6. Xcode crashed

How can I work around this and move the scenes?

Comment: Please report that bug. Xcode should never crash.

Comment: @Caleb, already did.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of selecting the view controller on the storyboard, select the scene from the storyboard navigation panel:

[image]

1. Once selected, hit Cmd + x
2. Select your new storyboard
3. Click on the storyboard (not in the navigation panel)
4. Hit Cmd + v

Done.

Comment: I had the same problem, this works perfectly fine. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Feel free to click that Vote Up button. :-)